# How should I delete the rows in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 14343 rows. But, when I check df.info() it shows 14365 rows as after the last row, there are cells which explain the column names and df considers it as a row. I tried the following code but it seems it did not work: `df.drop(df.index[14344, ])`

Comment: do all columns of those last rows show up as nulls, and are any other rows expected to have nulls for all columns?

Comment: How is the dataframe being created? If it is coming from a `csv` then you can use `skipfooter=22` to skips the lines at the bottom.

Comment: @jtweeder, no, some are strings as they contain just explanation

Comment: check the `df.dropna()` documentation, you can probably find a way to drop those rows based on the columns that show up null in that row. Without seeing an example dataset i could not totally advise, but this will work on many different files of this type versus hard coding a line stop.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html